# Understanding the association rule between classical to quantum data $|x\rangle=\frac{1}{|\vec x|_2}\sum_{i=1}^d x_i|i\rangle$

Tags: superposition, cq-states

I've been reading the paper on [Quantum Hopfield Networks by Rebentrost et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.03599.pdf) and I'm not sure to quite understand the association rule they mention on page 2.

Here's what they say :

Consider any $d$-dimensional vector $\vec{x} = [x_1,x_2,...,x_d]^T$. We associate it to the pure state $|x\rangle$ of a $d$-level quantum system according to $\vec{x} \rightarrow |\vec{x}|_2 \phantom{a}|x\rangle$ where $|\vec{x}|_2$ is the $l_2$-notm of $\vec{x}$ and $|x\rangle$ is given by $$|x\rangle = \frac{1}{|\vec{x}|_2} \sum_{i=1}^d{x_i|i\rangle}$$

Usually, when I don't understand a rule like this one, I try an example I try to build my understanding from it.

So let $\vec{x} = [1,0,1]^T$. We have that $|\vec{x}_2| = \sqrt{2}$ and therefore $|x\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \big( 1*|1\rangle + 0*|2\rangle + 1*|3\rangle \big)$ which doesn't make a lot of sense to me (in fact, usually when it comes to Quantum Computing, anything that deviates from the computational basis is confusing for me). From the way I see it, this is a quantum superposition. What I don't understand however, what kind of basis is this ?

Another way of phrasing this would be : How do I chose my initial vector such that the resulting vector from this association rule is in the computational basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be easier to understand how this works in terms of the computational basis if you choose $d$ to be some power of $2$. So let $d=2^n$ and then we will use $n = \log_2 d$ qubits to represent the quantum system. Then the indices $i=0,\dots, d-1$ (starting from $i=0$ for convenience) can be represented in their binary form $i := i_{n} i_{n-1} \dots i_1 $using $n$ bits, and we assign this binary form a value:
$$
i = \sum_{k=1}^n i_k 2^{k-1}
$$

and you can replace every basis state $|i\rangle$ in the encoding rule with its binary representation $|i_{n} i_{n-1} \dots i_1\rangle$ to represent the encoded state in terms of the computational basis of qubits.

Here's an example with $n=2$, and let $\vec{x} = [a, b, c, d]^T$ be the vector.  We use the encoding rule to write
\begin{align}
|x\rangle &= \frac{1}{|\vec{x}|_2} \sum_{i=0}^{d-1}{x_i|i\rangle} 
\\&=\frac{1}{|\vec{x}|_2} \left(a|0\rangle + b|1\rangle + c|2\rangle + d|3\rangle\right)
\\&=\frac{1}{|\vec{x}|_2} \left(a |00\rangle + b|01\rangle + c|10\rangle + d|11\rangle\right)
\end{align}
where in the last line I just replaced each $i$ with its binary representation $i_2 i_1$. This would still work if we had access to $n>2$ qubits and in general $n \geq \lceil \log_2 d \rceil$ qubits are sufficient for representing a $d$-dimensional quantum system. There are some minor adjustments needed if $d$ is not a power of $2$ but these are mostly procedural.

By the way, this rule is sometimes called "amplitude encoding" and its used widely in quantum algorithms for solving linear systems ([HHL](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3171)) and other quantum machine learning tasks. This may help you search for more resources to understand whats going on.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: Just one question though, why can you replace every basis state with its binary representation? Is there a theorem for it?

Comment: Its just a matter of representation - the information contained in the state isn't changing at all. Its the same way I could write either $3+5 = 8$ (decimal) or $0011 + 0101 = 1000$ (binary) as these statements both say the same thing in their respective bases.